# Java + MySQL - зашифровать существующие данные

Tags: java, mysql, decrypt, криптография

В коде Java реализовали шифрование и расшифровку сохраняемых данных следующим образом:

шифрование:

```
public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt) {
     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
     SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec("key".getBytes(), "AES");
     cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
     return new String(Hex.encodeHex(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes()), false));
    }
```

расшифровка:

```
public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt) {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    SecretKey secretKey = new 
    SecretKeySpec("key".getBytes(), "AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
    return new String(cipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex(strToDecrypt.toCharArray())));
    }
```

Все рабоает хорошо, при сохранении новых данных. Но в БД уже существовали не зашифрованные данные, которые также нужно зашифровать, используя скрипт MySQL.

Я пытаюсь сделать это следующим образом:

```
SELECT HEX((AES_ENCRYPT('value', 'key')));
```

Но когда в коде Java происходит расшифрование данных, которые были зашифрованы запросом SQL, то возникает ошибка:

```
decrjavax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption
```

Также, если одно и тоже значение зашифровать в коде Java и в БД, то на выходе получаются разные результаты строкового представления.

Подскажите каким образом мне воспроизвести запрос шифрования в БД MySQL, чтобы результат зашифрованного значения был анологичен результату получаему при шифровании в коде Java?

Comment: что вам мешает выбрать незашифрованные данные и прогнать их через java и зашифровать?

Comment: @ArchDemon требование заказчика, чтобы у него был запрос sql, которым он может зашифровать данные

Comment: Заказчик всё равно через java работать будет. Там шифруйте и расшифровывайте. На хабре, кстати, статья вышла о том как правильно шифровать и как неправильно подсказывают шифровать на SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение проблемы:**

Проблема в том что MySQL обрабатывает ключ шифрования. Ключ шифрования разбивается на 16-байтовые блоки, и MySQL выполняет XOR байтов из одного блока с байтами в предыдущем блоке. Если предоставленный пользователем ключ имеет длину менее 16 байтов, то ключ по существу дополняется нулевыми байтами, чтобы получить значение до 16 байтов.

Значение, которое должно быть зашифровано, также обрабатывается путем заполнения данных с помощью PKCS7.Но все, что он делает, это дополняет входные данные так, чтобы они располагались в 16-байтовых блоках. Байт, которым заполняются данные, эквивалентен количеству байтов заполнения, которые будут добавлены.

Поэтому необходимо обработать ключ шифрования, как это делает MySQL, а также дополнить входные данные с помощью PKCS7.

```
public class Demo {
    public static SecretKeySpec generateMySQLAESKey(final String key, final String encoding) {
        try {
            final byte[] finalKey = new byte[16];
            int i = 0;
            for(byte b : key.getBytes(encoding))
                finalKey[i++%16] ^= b;          
            return new SecretKeySpec(finalKey, "AES");
        } catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
 
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Decrypt
        final Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");                         
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, generateMySQLAESKey("your super secret passphrase", "UTF-8"));
        System.out.println(new String(decryptCipher.doFinal(Hex.decodeHex("56A34D7AB6225616799F6559AA388F07C2C9E53983111BDD5F49F36461AAD789".toCharArray()))));
 
        // Encrypt
        final Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");                         
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, generateMySQLAESKey("your super secret passphrase", "UTF-8"));      
        System.out.println(String.format("Select aes_decrypt(unhex('%s'), 'your super secret passphrase');", new String(Hex.encodeHex(encryptCipher.doFinal("Hallo nach Aachen".getBytes("UTF-8")))))); 
    }
}
```

[Ссылка на вопрос и ответ в англоязычном SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518447/aes-encryption-method-equivalent-to-mysql-aes-encrypt-function)

[Ссылка на статью из которой взят код и произведен разбор этой проблемы.](https://info.michael-simons.eu/2011/07/18/mysql-compatible-aes-encryption-decryption-in-java/)